# highcharts scatter with 4 quadrants

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

disclaimer: I'm totally new at working with these chart frameworks and I'm not super awesome at javascript either.

I created a mess of a scatter chart using highcharts [here](http://www.americanlawyer.com/PubArticleTAL.jsp?id=1202602068318&slreturn=20130507132926).

It must be changed to have 4 color quadrants like this one [here](http://www.americanlawyer.com/PubArticleTAL.jsp?id=1202596057627&slreturn=20130319124635).

Problem is that this one doesn't have the negative and positive y axis and I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this happen somewhere in the middle of the data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Just [mocked up this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fEySL/), based on [previous work](http://jsfiddle.net/aTz7N/65/) by [@jlbriggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011544/jlbriggs).

[image]

To add the quadrant coloring, I resorted to drawing it with the `chart.renderer` (I couldn't find a better way using axis plotBands):

```
function(chart) { // on complete

    var width = chart.plotBox.width / 2.0;
    var height = chart.plotBox.height / 2.0 + 1;

    chart.renderer.rect(chart.plotBox.x,                      
                            chart.plotBox.y, width, height, 1)
            .attr({
                fill: 'lightblue',
                zIndex: 0
            })
            .add();

     chart.renderer.rect(chart.plotBox.x + width,                      
                         chart.plotBox.y, width, height, 1)
            .attr({
                fill: 'yellow',
                zIndex: 0
            })
            .add();

    chart.renderer.rect(chart.plotBox.x,                      
                        chart.plotBox.y + height, width, height, 1)
            .attr({
                fill: 'yellow',
                zIndex: 0
            })
            .add();

    chart.renderer.rect(chart.plotBox.x + width,                      
                        chart.plotBox.y + height, width, height, 1)
            .attr({
                fill: 'lightblue',
                zIndex: 0
            })
            .add();        
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the blocks on the y-axis of different heights? I'm trying to make the fist tick go to 70% of the height and the remaining 30% of 100. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

I learned a lot from Mark's answer above - works great. I ended up with a slightly different solution though - this approach calculates the quadrant coordinates based on chart values using `.toPixels(value, false)` instead of plotBox dimensions. This is especially important if you need to redraw to support zoom, etc.

```
chart: {
    height: 500,
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy',
    events: {
        load: function () {

            //Calculate the quadrant coordinates; toPixels uses point values
            var x0 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(0, false);
            var x1 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(50, false);
            var x2 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(100, false);

            //The y axis coordinates return values from TOP LEFT origin (opposite order)
            var y0 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(100, false);
            var y1 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(50, false);
            var y2 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0, false);

            //Draw the quadrants
            chart.renderer.rect(x0, y1, x1 - x0, y2 - y1, 1).attr({ fill: 'lightblue', zIndex: 0 }).add();
            chart.renderer.rect(x0, y0, x1 - x0, y1 - y0, 1).attr({ fill: 'lightyellow', zIndex: 0 }).add();
            chart.renderer.rect(x1, y0, x2 - x1, y1 - y0, 1).attr({ fill: 'lightblue', zIndex: 0 }).add();
            chart.renderer.rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1, 1).attr({ fill: 'lightyellow', zIndex: 0 }).add();

            }
        },
    ...other chart options...
}
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: It was helpful indeed! I was looking for exactly this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the number of series you have in your plot, you can achieve it like [Scatter with Quadrants](http://jsfiddle.net/ashutosh_srivastav/hnw00u0b/3/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy',
    height: 400

},
title: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: {
      min:0,
    max:256,
    tickInterval:16,
    plotLines:[{
        value:128,
        color:'#666',
        dashStyle: 'solid',
        width:2,
        zIndex: 5
    }],
    labels:{
        enabled: false
        },        
    gridLineWidth:1,
    showLastLabel:true,
    showFirstLabel:false,
    lineColor:'#ccc',
    lineWidth:1,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true
},
yAxis: {
      min:0,
    max:256,
            plotLines:[{
        value:128,
        dashStyle: 'solid',
        color:'#666',
        width:2,
        zIndex: 5
    }],
    labels:{
        enabled: false
        },
    tickInterval :16,
    gridLineWidth:1,
    showLastLabel:true,
    showFirstLabel:false,
    lineColor:'#ccc'
},

plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        marker: {
            radius: 3
        },
        tooltip: {              
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    series:{
        animation :  false,
        shadow: false,
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }
},
series: [{
    color: 'rgba(225, 225, 225)',
    data: [[6.0,7.0],[6.0,72.0],[6.0,73.0],[6.0,87.0],[6.0,103.0],[6.0,120.0],[6.0,134.0],[6.0,151.0],[6.0,152.0],[6.0,169.0],[6.0,248.0],[7.0,7.0],[7.0,24.0],[7.0,40.0],[7.0,71.0],[7.0,74.0],[7.0,86.0],[7.0,88.0],[7.0,89.0],[7.0,103.0],[7.0,122.0],[7.0,134.0],[7.0,135.0],[7.0,182.0],[7.0,213.0],[7.0,230.0],[8.0,8.0],[8.0,9.0],[8.0,38.0],[8.0,40.0],[8.0,57.0],[8.0,72.0],[8.0,89.0],[8.0,102.0],[8.0,104.0],[8.0,119.0],[8.0,134.0],[8.0,136.0],[8.0,137.0],[8.0,150.0],[8.0,151.0],[8.0,152.0],[8.0,167.0],[8.0,183.0],[8.0,186.0],[8.0,199.0],[8.0,214.0],[8.0,215.0],[8.0,229.0],[8.0,231.0],[8.0,247.0],[8.0,248.0],[8.0,249.0],[9.0,39.0],[9.0,40.0],[9.0,41.0],[9.0,54.0],[9.0,56.0],[9.0,71.0],[9.0,88.0],[9.0,135.0],[9.0,150.0],[9.0,152.0],[9.0,169.0],[9.0,183.0],[9.0,216.0],[10.0,72.0],[10.0,167.0],[10.0,200.0],[10.0,231.0],[10.0,248.0],[21.0,6.0],[21.0,88.0],[22.0,40.0],[22.0,55.0],[22.0,73.0],[22.0,89.0],[22.0,119.0],[22.0,122.0],[22.0,135.0],[22.0,150.0],[22.0,152.0],[22.0,167.0],[22.0,183.0],[22.0,184.0],[22.0,246.0],[23.0,9.0],[23.0,39.0],[23.0,55.0],[23.0,57.0],[23.0,73.0],[23.0,87.0],[23.0,88.0],[23.0,121.0],[23.0,137.0],[23.0,151.0],[23.0,167.0],[23.0,199.0],[23.0,200.0],[23.0,231.0],[23.0,232.0],[23.0,247.0],[23.0,248.0],[24.0,6.0],[24.0,22.0],[24.0,23.0],[24.0,25.0],[24.0,38.0],[24.0,54.0],[24.0,55.0],[24.0,58.0],[24.0,71.0],[24.0,101.0],[24.0,103.0],[24.0,104.0],[24.0,105.0],[24.0,137.0],[24.0,152.0],[24.0,167.0],[24.0,183.0],[24.0,199.0],[24.0,200.0],[24.0,201.0],[24.0,231.0],[24.0,232.0],[24.0,250.0],[25.0,8.0],[25.0,38.0],[25.0,41.0],[25.0,54.0],[25.0,56.0],[25.0,103.0],[25.0,119.0],[25.0,138.0],[25.0,168.0],[25.0,184.0],[25.0,199.0],[25.0,216.0],[26.0,184.0],[37.0,25.0],[37.0,184.0],[37.0,199.0],[38.0,7.0],[38.0,8.0],[38.0,24.0],[38.0,25.0],[38.0,103.0],[38.0,121.0],[38.0,122.0],[38.0,151.0],[38.0,167.0],[38.0,199.0],[38.0,232.0],[39.0,38.0],[39.0,40.0],[39.0,55.0],[39.0,71.0],[39.0,72.0],[39.0,86.0],[39.0,87.0],[39.0,103.0],[39.0,118.0],[39.0,119.0],[39.0,120.0],[39.0,136.0],[39.0,151.0],[39.0,153.0],[39.0,166.0],[39.0,168.0],[39.0,200.0],[39.0,201.0],[39.0,215.0],[39.0,216.0],[39.0,217.0],[39.0,249.0],[40.0,8.0],[40.0,22.0],[40.0,40.0],[40.0,56.0],[40.0,71.0],[40.0,86.0],[40.0,104.0],[40.0,119.0],[40.0,183.0],[40.0,185.0],[40.0,200.0],[40.0,201.0],[40.0,247.0],[40.0,248.0],[41.0,8.0],[41.0,70.0],[41.0,71.0],[41.0,87.0],[41.0,102.0],[41.0,103.0],[41.0,104.0],[41.0,121.0],[41.0,151.0],[41.0,152.0],[41.0,153.0],[41.0,200.0],[41.0,217.0],[53.0,103.0],[54.0,8.0],[54.0,23.0],[54.0,56.0],[54.0,72.0],[54.0,73.0],[54.0,104.0],[54.0,151.0],[54.0,167.0],[54.0,199.0],[54.0,215.0],[54.0,217.0],[54.0,248.0],[55.0,23.0],[55.0,40.0],[55.0,53.0],[55.0,55.0],[55.0,58.0],[55.0,72.0],[55.0,87.0],[55.0,88.0],[55.0,104.0],[55.0,119.0],[55.0,136.0],[55.0,137.0],[55.0,151.0],[55.0,166.0],[55.0,169.0],[55.0,184.0],[55.0,200.0],[55.0,214.0],[55.0,216.0],[55.0,231.0],[55.0,232.0],[55.0,233.0],[55.0,247.0],[55.0,249.0],[56.0,7.0],[56.0,8.0],[56.0,9.0],[56.0,23.0],[56.0,38.0],[56.0,42.0],[56.0,56.0],[56.0,70.0],[56.0,88.0],[56.0,89.0],[56.0,122.0],[56.0,135.0],[56.0,136.0],[56.0,152.0],[56.0,153.0],[56.0,166.0],[56.0,167.0],[56.0,168.0],[56.0,169.0],[56.0,185.0],[56.0,200.0],[56.0,215.0],[56.0,216.0],[57.0,7.0],[57.0,56.0],[57.0,103.0],[57.0,121.0],[57.0,135.0],[57.0,151.0],[57.0,167.0],[57.0,215.0],[57.0,247.0],[58.0,9.0],[70.0,8.0],[70.0,41.0],[70.0,55.0],[70.0,56.0],[70.0,72.0],[70.0,119.0],[70.0,151.0],[70.0,181.0],[70.0,184.0],[70.0,201.0],[70.0,247.0],[70.0,248.0],[71.0,8.0],[71.0,9.0],[71.0,39.0],[71.0,56.0],[71.0,73.0],[71.0,87.0],[71.0,89.0],[71.0,103.0],[71.0,104.0],[71.0,118.0],[71.0,119.0],[71.0,120.0],[71.0,166.0],[71.0,167.0],[71.0,168.0],[71.0,183.0],[71.0,217.0],[71.0,247.0],[72.0,23.0],[72.0,40.0],[72.0,71.0],[72.0,73.0],[72.0,87.0],[72.0,89.0],[72.0,102.0],[72.0,137.0],[72.0,152.0],[72.0,153.0],[72.0,216.0],[72.0,230.0],[72.0,231.0],[72.0,233.0],[72.0,249.0],[72.0,250.0],[73.0,8.0],[73.0,9.0],[73.0,23.0],[73.0,74.0],[73.0,137.0],[73.0,199.0],[73.0,200.0],[73.0,216.0],[73.0,217.0],[73.0,247.0],[74.0,7.0],[74.0,87.0],[86.0,23.0],[86.0,40.0],[86.0,56.0],[86.0,72.0],[86.0,135.0],[86.0,136.0],[86.0,168.0],[87.0,7.0],[87.0,24.0],[87.0,55.0],[87.0,70.0],[87.0,72.0],[87.0,86.0],[87.0,87.0],[87.0,90.0],[87.0,118.0],[87.0,119.0],[87.0,120.0],[87.0,136.0],[87.0,151.0],[87.0,166.0],[87.0,169.0],[87.0,201.0],[87.0,202.0],[87.0,215.0],[87.0,216.0],[87.0,246.0],[88.0,23.0],[88.0,39.0],[88.0,71.0],[88.0,73.0],[88.0,87.0],[88.0,88.0],[88.0,89.0],[88.0,90.0],[88.0,105.0],[88.0,106.0],[88.0,134.0],[88.0,152.0],[88.0,153.0],[88.0,167.0],[88.0,169.0],[88.0,215.0],[88.0,217.0],[88.0,231.0],[88.0,248.0],[88.0,249.0],[89.0,8.0],[89.0,23.0],[89.0,24.0],[89.0,39.0],[89.0,71.0],[89.0,103.0],[89.0,104.0],[89.0,119.0],[89.0,135.0],[89.0,152.0],[89.0,154.0],[89.0,167.0],[89.0,216.0],[89.0,245.0],[90.0,55.0],[90.0,217.0],[102.0,7.0],[102.0,24.0],[102.0,71.0],[102.0,184.0],[102.0,199.0],[102.0,231.0],[102.0,232.0],[102.0,247.0],[103.0,23.0],[103.0,24.0],[103.0,25.0],[103.0,42.0],[103.0,55.0],[103.0,57.0],[103.0,87.0],[103.0,120.0],[103.0,136.0],[103.0,150.0],[103.0,152.0],[103.0,201.0],[103.0,217.0],[104.0,23.0],[104.0,24.0],[104.0,25.0],[104.0,40.0],[104.0,55.0],[104.0,87.0],[104.0,88.0],[104.0,89.0],[104.0,104.0],[104.0,105.0],[104.0,120.0],[104.0,151.0],[104.0,152.0],[104.0,153.0],[104.0,167.0],[104.0,168.0],[104.0,182.0],[104.0,185.0],[104.0,199.0],[104.0,201.0],[104.0,216.0],[104.0,231.0],[104.0,232.0],[104.0,246.0],[104.0,247.0],[104.0,248.0],[105.0,90.0],[105.0,121.0],[105.0,135.0],[105.0,154.0],[105.0,167.0],[105.0,183.0],[105.0,214.0],[105.0,216.0],[105.0,247.0],[117.0,24.0],[118.0,24.0],[118.0,39.0],[118.0,57.0],[118.0,72.0],[118.0,135.0],[118.0,168.0],[118.0,200.0],[118.0,215.0],[118.0,216.0],[119.0,7.0],[119.0,41.0],[119.0,71.0],[119.0,72.0],[119.0,104.0],[119.0,105.0],[119.0,119.0],[119.0,152.0],[119.0,167.0],[119.0,183.0],[119.0,184.0],[119.0,185.0],[119.0,231.0],[119.0,248.0],[119.0,249.0],[120.0,8.0],[120.0,22.0],[120.0,25.0],[120.0,41.0],[120.0,54.0],[120.0,55.0],[120.0,72.0],[120.0,88.0],[120.0,119.0],[120.0,120.0],[120.0,151.0],[120.0,167.0],[120.0,168.0],[120.0,200.0],[120.0,201.0],[120.0,232.0],[121.0,24.0],[121.0,136.0],[121.0,151.0],[121.0,169.0],[121.0,231.0],[121.0,232.0],[121.0,247.0],[133.0,247.0],[134.0,22.0],[134.0,73.0],[134.0,135.0],[134.0,152.0],[134.0,168.0],[134.0,217.0],[134.0,232.0],[134.0,233.0],[135.0,7.0],[135.0,25.0],[135.0,38.0],[135.0,55.0],[135.0,71.0],[135.0,87.0],[135.0,89.0],[135.0,103.0],[135.0,119.0],[135.0,134.0],[135.0,137.0],[135.0,166.0],[135.0,168.0],[135.0,169.0],[135.0,184.0],[135.0,185.0],[135.0,218.0],[135.0,231.0],[135.0,247.0],[135.0,248.0],[136.0,23.0],[136.0,25.0],[136.0,38.0],[136.0,40.0],[136.0,55.0],[136.0,57.0],[136.0,70.0],[136.0,72.0],[136.0,86.0],[136.0,102.0],[136.0,119.0],[136.0,121.0],[136.0,134.0],[136.0,135.0],[136.0,136.0],[136.0,137.0],[136.0,149.0],[136.0,150.0],[136.0,151.0],[136.0,152.0],[136.0,154.0],[136.0,168.0],[136.0,182.0],[136.0,184.0],[136.0,185.0],[136.0,199.0],[136.0,200.0],[136.0,246.0],[136.0,247.0],[137.0,55.0],[137.0,72.0],[137.0,88.0],[137.0,119.0],[137.0,120.0],[137.0,135.0],[137.0,151.0],[137.0,152.0],[137.0,183.0],[137.0,199.0],[137.0,230.0],[137.0,248.0],[149.0,170.0],[150.0,8.0],[150.0,87.0],[150.0,120.0],[150.0,151.0],[150.0,168.0],[150.0,231.0],[150.0,232.0],[150.0,247.0],[150.0,248.0],[151.0,23.0],[151.0,38.0],[151.0,40.0],[151.0,57.0],[151.0,71.0],[151.0,105.0],[151.0,119.0],[151.0,121.0],[151.0,152.0],[151.0,182.0],[151.0,185.0],[151.0,199.0],[151.0,200.0],[151.0,214.0],[151.0,230.0],[151.0,231.0],[151.0,246.0],[151.0,249.0],[152.0,39.0],[152.0,40.0],[152.0,72.0],[152.0,87.0],[152.0,88.0],[152.0,89.0],[152.0,104.0],[152.0,105.0],[152.0,118.0],[152.0,150.0],[152.0,151.0],[152.0,153.0],[152.0,166.0],[152.0,169.0],[152.0,216.0],[152.0,231.0],[152.0,247.0],[152.0,248.0],[153.0,41.0],[153.0,54.0],[153.0,56.0],[153.0,87.0],[153.0,101.0],[153.0,120.0],[153.0,136.0],[153.0,152.0],[153.0,168.0],[153.0,215.0],[153.0,216.0],[153.0,233.0],[153.0,247.0],[154.0,102.0],[165.0,232.0],[166.0,8.0],[166.0,9.0],[166.0,87.0],[166.0,89.0],[166.0,120.0],[166.0,135.0],[166.0,250.0],[167.0,6.0],[167.0,7.0],[167.0,8.0],[167.0,23.0],[167.0,24.0],[167.0,39.0],[167.0,56.0],[167.0,71.0],[167.0,72.0],[167.0,73.0],[167.0,87.0],[167.0,103.0],[167.0,136.0],[167.0,137.0],[167.0,168.0],[167.0,183.0],[167.0,199.0],[167.0,215.0],[167.0,216.0],[167.0,230.0],[167.0,232.0],[168.0,21.0],[168.0,24.0],[168.0,25.0],[168.0,38.0],[168.0,57.0],[168.0,88.0],[168.0,103.0],[168.0,104.0],[168.0,119.0],[168.0,120.0],[168.0,121.0],[168.0,134.0],[168.0,136.0],[168.0,152.0],[168.0,154.0],[168.0,183.0],[168.0,198.0],[168.0,199.0],[168.0,200.0],[168.0,214.0],[168.0,231.0],[168.0,248.0],[169.0,8.0],[169.0,38.0],[169.0,39.0],[169.0,90.0],[169.0,103.0],[169.0,151.0],[169.0,200.0],[169.0,215.0],[169.0,250.0],[170.0,152.0],[170.0,249.0],[180.0,9.0],[182.0,40.0],[182.0,89.0],[182.0,104.0],[182.0,168.0],[182.0,169.0],[182.0,182.0],[182.0,199.0],[182.0,215.0],[182.0,231.0],[182.0,232.0],[182.0,246.0],[183.0,6.0],[183.0,10.0],[183.0,24.0],[183.0,25.0],[183.0,72.0],[183.0,104.0],[183.0,105.0],[183.0,119.0],[183.0,135.0],[183.0,136.0],[183.0,137.0],[183.0,152.0],[183.0,169.0],[183.0,183.0],[183.0,184.0],[183.0,199.0],[183.0,200.0],[183.0,201.0],[183.0,215.0],[183.0,216.0],[183.0,247.0],[184.0,7.0],[184.0,8.0],[184.0,24.0],[184.0,70.0],[184.0,88.0],[184.0,119.0],[184.0,121.0],[184.0,137.0],[184.0,169.0],[184.0,183.0],[184.0,200.0],[184.0,217.0],[184.0,230.0],[184.0,246.0],[184.0,248.0],[185.0,42.0],[185.0,57.0],[185.0,87.0],[185.0,168.0],[185.0,185.0],[185.0,216.0],[186.0,185.0],[197.0,8.0],[197.0,24.0],[198.0,8.0],[198.0,9.0],[198.0,23.0],[198.0,39.0],[198.0,103.0],[198.0,138.0],[198.0,183.0],[198.0,199.0],[198.0,200.0],[198.0,249.0],[199.0,9.0],[199.0,22.0],[199.0,23.0],[199.0,39.0],[199.0,56.0],[199.0,57.0],[199.0,71.0],[199.0,88.0],[199.0,105.0],[199.0,120.0],[199.0,135.0],[199.0,201.0],[199.0,214.0],[199.0,215.0],[199.0,216.0],[199.0,231.0],[199.0,234.0],[199.0,247.0],[200.0,24.0],[200.0,39.0],[200.0,55.0],[200.0,73.0],[200.0,88.0],[200.0,89.0],[200.0,104.0],[200.0,118.0],[200.0,119.0],[200.0,134.0],[200.0,135.0],[200.0,152.0],[200.0,168.0],[200.0,198.0],[200.0,199.0],[200.0,215.0],[200.0,230.0],[200.0,233.0],[201.0,8.0],[201.0,24.0],[201.0,25.0],[201.0,104.0],[201.0,151.0],[201.0,186.0],[201.0,201.0],[202.0,41.0],[203.0,8.0],[213.0,40.0],[213.0,134.0],[214.0,9.0],[214.0,24.0],[214.0,104.0],[214.0,184.0],[214.0,217.0],[214.0,246.0],[215.0,9.0],[215.0,24.0],[215.0,25.0],[215.0,39.0],[215.0,40.0],[215.0,57.0],[215.0,71.0],[215.0,73.0],[215.0,87.0],[215.0,119.0],[215.0,135.0],[215.0,136.0],[215.0,152.0],[215.0,153.0],[215.0,184.0],[215.0,185.0],[215.0,200.0],[215.0,215.0],[215.0,232.0],[215.0,248.0],[216.0,8.0],[216.0,10.0],[216.0,25.0],[216.0,73.0],[216.0,89.0],[216.0,103.0],[216.0,104.0],[216.0,119.0],[216.0,136.0],[216.0,137.0],[216.0,153.0],[216.0,167.0],[216.0,170.0],[216.0,199.0],[216.0,214.0],[216.0,217.0],[216.0,233.0],[216.0,246.0],[217.0,23.0],[217.0,24.0],[217.0,41.0],[217.0,56.0],[217.0,72.0],[217.0,104.0],[217.0,135.0],[217.0,167.0],[217.0,168.0],[217.0,182.0],[217.0,230.0],[218.0,120.0],[229.0,72.0],[229.0,200.0],[230.0,40.0],[230.0,54.0],[230.0,55.0],[230.0,71.0],[230.0,72.0],[230.0,120.0],[230.0,135.0],[230.0,151.0],[230.0,166.0],[230.0,168.0],[230.0,183.0],[230.0,247.0],[230.0,249.0],[231.0,7.0],[231.0,9.0],[231.0,10.0],[231.0,22.0],[231.0,72.0],[231.0,87.0],[231.0,101.0],[231.0,103.0],[231.0,135.0],[231.0,136.0],[231.0,150.0],[231.0,185.0],[231.0,186.0],[231.0,199.0],[231.0,217.0],[231.0,232.0],[231.0,247.0],[232.0,7.0],[232.0,8.0],[232.0,54.0],[232.0,56.0],[232.0,72.0],[232.0,89.0],[232.0,136.0],[232.0,137.0],[232.0,152.0],[232.0,169.0],[232.0,183.0],[232.0,184.0],[232.0,198.0],[232.0,199.0],[232.0,215.0],[232.0,216.0],[232.0,217.0],[233.0,25.0],[233.0,42.0],[233.0,89.0],[233.0,105.0],[233.0,136.0],[233.0,151.0],[233.0,165.0],[233.0,184.0],[233.0,199.0],[233.0,215.0],[233.0,233.0],[245.0,8.0],[245.0,40.0],[245.0,119.0],[245.0,120.0],[245.0,216.0],[246.0,10.0],[246.0,24.0],[246.0,38.0],[246.0,39.0],[246.0,57.0],[246.0,87.0],[246.0,89.0],[246.0,120.0],[246.0,153.0],[246.0,167.0],[246.0,183.0],[246.0,213.0],[246.0,216.0],[246.0,231.0],[246.0,247.0],[247.0,8.0],[247.0,10.0],[247.0,22.0],[247.0,23.0],[247.0,25.0],[247.0,26.0],[247.0,39.0],[247.0,54.0],[247.0,55.0],[247.0,71.0],[247.0,72.0],[247.0,73.0],[247.0,88.0],[247.0,89.0],[247.0,104.0],[247.0,118.0],[247.0,135.0],[247.0,138.0],[247.0,151.0],[247.0,168.0],[247.0,182.0],[247.0,184.0],[247.0,200.0],[247.0,218.0],[247.0,230.0],[247.0,231.0],[247.0,232.0],[247.0,246.0],[247.0,247.0],[248.0,7.0],[248.0,25.0],[248.0,39.0],[248.0,40.0],[248.0,73.0],[248.0,102.0],[248.0,105.0],[248.0,135.0],[248.0,151.0],[248.0,153.0],[248.0,166.0],[248.0,169.0],[248.0,183.0],[248.0,184.0],[248.0,200.0],[248.0,214.0],[248.0,215.0],[248.0,230.0],[248.0,232.0],[248.0,248.0],[249.0,8.0],[249.0,9.0],[249.0,23.0],[249.0,24.0],[249.0,40.0],[249.0,55.0],[249.0,72.0],[249.0,89.0],[249.0,150.0],[249.0,152.0],[249.0,153.0],[249.0,182.0],[7.0,8.0],[7.0,87.0],[7.0,119.0],[7.0,136.0],[7.0,151.0],[7.0,199.0],[8.0,39.0],[8.0,56.0],[8.0,73.0],[8.0,103.0],[8.0,120.0],[8.0,232.0],[9.0,185.0],[22.0,39.0],[23.0,24.0],[23.0,71.0],[23.0,104.0],[23.0,120.0],[23.0,215.0],[24.0,73.0],[24.0,87.0],[24.0,119.0],[24.0,135.0],[24.0,136.0],[24.0,184.0],[25.0,25.0],[25.0,120.0],[39.0,24.0],[39.0,104.0],[39.0,167.0],[39.0,231.0],[39.0,232.0],[40.0,7.0],[40.0,88.0],[40.0,136.0],[40.0,168.0],[40.0,199.0],[40.0,215.0],[40.0,216.0],[40.0,231.0],[40.0,232.0],[41.0,201.0],[41.0,231.0],[54.0,24.0],[54.0,200.0],[55.0,7.0],[55.0,56.0],[55.0,57.0],[55.0,152.0],[55.0,183.0],[55.0,199.0],[56.0,24.0],[56.0,87.0],[56.0,103.0],[57.0,89.0],[57.0,104.0],[57.0,216.0],[71.0,23.0],[71.0,24.0],[71.0,71.0],[71.0,72.0],[71.0,135.0],[71.0,215.0],[71.0,216.0],[71.0,248.0],[72.0,24.0],[72.0,55.0],[72.0,88.0],[72.0,103.0],[72.0,104.0],[72.0,105.0],[72.0,135.0],[72.0,136.0],[72.0,150.0],[72.0,183.0],[73.0,40.0],[87.0,56.0],[87.0,137.0],[87.0,183.0],[87.0,200.0],[88.0,24.0],[88.0,55.0],[88.0,72.0],[88.0,119.0],[88.0,120.0],[88.0,136.0],[88.0,168.0],[88.0,184.0],[88.0,200.0],[88.0,216.0],[89.0,233.0],[102.0,56.0],[102.0,135.0],[102.0,167.0],[103.0,7.0],[103.0,71.0],[103.0,103.0],[103.0,104.0],[103.0,135.0],[103.0,151.0],[103.0,183.0],[103.0,184.0],[103.0,200.0],[103.0,215.0],[103.0,231.0],[103.0,247.0],[104.0,72.0],[104.0,103.0],[104.0,121.0],[104.0,215.0],[105.0,104.0],[105.0,168.0],[117.0,39.0],[118.0,40.0],[119.0,24.0],[119.0,39.0],[119.0,56.0],[119.0,87.0],[119.0,135.0],[119.0,168.0],[119.0,200.0],[119.0,230.0],[119.0,232.0],[120.0,40.0],[120.0,71.0],[120.0,135.0],[120.0,199.0],[120.0,216.0],[120.0,248.0],[134.0,8.0],[134.0,40.0],[134.0,56.0],[134.0,231.0],[135.0,9.0],[135.0,120.0],[135.0,136.0],[135.0,199.0],[135.0,216.0],[136.0,7.0],[136.0,8.0],[136.0,56.0],[136.0,167.0],[136.0,201.0],[136.0,232.0],[136.0,248.0],[137.0,71.0],[150.0,167.0],[151.0,39.0],[151.0,41.0],[151.0,56.0],[151.0,103.0],[151.0,168.0],[151.0,184.0],[151.0,216.0],[152.0,23.0],[152.0,24.0],[152.0,55.0],[152.0,56.0],[152.0,73.0],[152.0,103.0],[152.0,120.0],[152.0,168.0],[152.0,201.0],[152.0,215.0],[166.0,184.0],[167.0,88.0],[167.0,119.0],[167.0,120.0],[167.0,152.0],[167.0,184.0],[167.0,249.0],[168.0,167.0],[168.0,184.0],[168.0,215.0],[169.0,231.0],[182.0,136.0],[182.0,152.0],[182.0,201.0],[182.0,248.0],[183.0,8.0],[183.0,55.0],[183.0,56.0],[183.0,88.0],[183.0,103.0],[183.0,168.0],[183.0,231.0],[183.0,232.0],[183.0,248.0],[184.0,39.0],[184.0,104.0],[184.0,136.0],[184.0,167.0],[184.0,215.0],[184.0,216.0],[185.0,7.0],[185.0,55.0],[198.0,72.0],[198.0,184.0],[198.0,248.0],[199.0,87.0],[199.0,103.0],[199.0,151.0],[199.0,182.0],[199.0,184.0],[200.0,6.0],[200.0,8.0],[200.0,25.0],[200.0,103.0],[200.0,120.0],[200.0,200.0],[200.0,231.0],[201.0,55.0],[214.0,56.0],[215.0,23.0],[215.0,86.0],[215.0,118.0],[215.0,120.0],[215.0,151.0],[215.0,199.0],[215.0,214.0],[216.0,24.0],[216.0,151.0],[216.0,152.0],[216.0,184.0],[216.0,216.0],[230.0,103.0],[231.0,88.0],[231.0,120.0],[231.0,167.0],[231.0,215.0],[232.0,41.0],[232.0,88.0],[232.0,119.0],[232.0,167.0],[232.0,168.0],[232.0,248.0],[233.0,103.0],[233.0,137.0],[246.0,119.0],[246.0,184.0],[246.0,215.0],[247.0,56.0],[247.0,87.0],[247.0,136.0],[247.0,167.0],[247.0,183.0],[247.0,185.0],[247.0,199.0],[247.0,214.0],[247.0,216.0],[247.0,248.0],[247.0,249.0],[248.0,57.0],[248.0,72.0],[248.0,103.0],[248.0,104.0],[248.0,231.0],[248.0,247.0],[249.0,39.0],[249.0,168.0],[7.0,120.0],[7.0,200.0],[7.0,231.0],[8.0,87.0],[23.0,152.0],[39.0,169.0],[40.0,23.0],[40.0,39.0],[40.0,184.0],[55.0,71.0],[56.0,104.0],[56.0,120.0],[56.0,199.0],[71.0,40.0],[71.0,151.0],[71.0,199.0],[71.0,201.0],[72.0,215.0],[73.0,232.0],[87.0,104.0],[87.0,152.0],[87.0,153.0],[88.0,8.0],[88.0,247.0],[103.0,72.0],[104.0,71.0],[104.0,119.0],[104.0,200.0],[119.0,88.0],[119.0,120.0],[120.0,24.0],[120.0,103.0],[120.0,184.0],[135.0,8.0],[135.0,72.0],[135.0,135.0],[135.0,200.0],[136.0,71.0],[136.0,183.0],[137.0,215.0],[150.0,152.0],[151.0,24.0],[151.0,248.0],[152.0,8.0],[152.0,119.0],[152.0,121.0],[166.0,88.0],[167.0,40.0],[167.0,247.0],[168.0,23.0],[183.0,40.0],[184.0,71.0],[184.0,135.0],[184.0,199.0],[185.0,247.0],[199.0,7.0],[199.0,152.0],[200.0,41.0],[200.0,71.0],[216.0,72.0],[216.0,183.0],[231.0,24.0],[231.0,104.0],[231.0,152.0],[231.0,231.0],[246.0,136.0],[246.0,232.0],[248.0,136.0],[7.0,137.0],[7.0,168.0],[8.0,168.0],[24.0,247.0],[39.0,135.0],[56.0,39.0],[87.0,247.0],[119.0,247.0],[135.0,104.0],[135.0,152.0],[151.0,8.0],[151.0,104.0],[152.0,199.0],[183.0,87.0],[183.0,167.0],[184.0,72.0],[215.0,168.0]]

}]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem to get quadrants with positive values only. Now I found there are three ways by which we can do this.

1. You can also use HighCharts Plugin [crossing-specific-value](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values).
   This feature lets you specify specific values where the axis should cross.

   ```
   xAxis: {
       crossing: 1,
   },
   yAxis: {
       crossing: 3,
   },
   ```

   See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jsCJF/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=jsCJF)
2. You can use [xAxis.plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines) and [yAxis.plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) to have quadrants.

   ```
   xAxis: {
       plotLines: [{
           color: 'blue',
           width: 2,
           value: 5.5
       }]
   },
   yAxis: {
       plotLines: [{
           color: 'blue',
           width: 2,
           value: 125
       }]
   },
   ```

   See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SomnathMuluk/zn6d3gnq/)
3. The solution given by @Mark, to fill colors in the sections so it fills like quadrant.